# Regexp JSON filtering in LogQL

Tags: json, grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I'd like to translate Kibana query like to following to LogQL:

```
host:("test1-myservice-*") AND level:ERROR 
AND NOT logger_name:"com.example.ExampleClass" 
AND _exists_:stack_trace 
AND NOT stack_trace:(
    "interrupted"
    OR "Read timed out"
    OR "java.lang.InterruptedException"
)
```

I have tried the following in Grafana Explore but it does not return any records for our JSON log messages:

```
{host=~"test1-myservice-.*"} | json 
| logger_name != "com.example.ExampleClass" 
| stack_trace !="" 
| stack_trace =~ ".*InterruptedException.*"
```

While using `!=` instead of `=~` it returns all records:

```
{host=~"test1-myservice-.*"} | json 
| logger_name != "com.example.ExampleClass" 
| stack_trace !="" 
| stack_trace !~ ".*InterruptedException.*"
```

If I'm right the following applies from the documentations to the `stack_trace` field of the JSON log line:

> String type work exactly like Prometheus label matchers use in log stream selector. This means you can use the same operations (=,!=,=~,!~).

Source: [Label filter expression](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#label-filter-expression)

The following seems to work but it seems awkward:

```
{host=~"test1-myservice-.*"} | json 
| logger_name != "com.example.ExampleClass" 
| stack_trace !="" 
!~ ".*InterruptedException.*|.*Read timed out.*"
| json
```

Furthermore, if I'm right, it searches for `InterruptedException` and `Read timed out` substrings in the complete JSON string instead of its `stack_trace` field only.

Is there a more LogQL-ish way to translate the Kibana query above to LogQL? Should the `!~` operator work in this case?

Environment: Grafana 7.5.4 / 8.2.3, Loki: 2.4.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
{host=~"test1-myservice-.*"} | json 
| logger_name != "com.example.ExampleClass" 
| stack_trace !="" 
| stack_trace !~ "(?s).*InterruptedException.*"
```

Note the `(?s)` which enables matching new lines for the regex `.` character. (The `stack_trace` field of the JSON log message usually contain multiple lines.)

This is also mentioned in the [Log stream selector part of the documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#log-stream-selector):

> Note: The `=~` regex operator is fully anchored, meaning regex must match against the entire string, including newlines. The regex `.` character does not match newlines by default. If you want the regex dot character to match newlines you can use the single-line flag, like so: `(?s)search_term.+` matches `search_term\n`.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure how your log lines look exactly, but I think you don't need to extract the labels out (by using `| json`

This is a pretty useful article on how to write queries.
[how-to-create-fast-queries-with-lokis-logql-to-filter-terabytes-of-logs-in-seconds](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/12/08/how-to-create-fast-queries-with-lokis-logql-to-filter-terabytes-of-logs-in-seconds/)
You can also make use of the new [Pattern parser](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/08/09/new-in-loki-2.3-logql-pattern-parser-makes-it-easier-to-extract-data-from-unstructured-logs/) instead of the regex if you want to make the query more readable.

So without really knowing how your log lines look, I think this should work well:

```
{host=~"test1-myservice-.*"}
!= "com.example.ExampleClass" 
!~ ".*InterruptedException.*|.*Read timed out.*"
```

Based on your needs you can also make use of the Pattern parser I've mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The first link has a great overview which I've not been completely aware of. Our logs files contain JSON objects in every line. In my example `ExampleClass` is searched only in the `logger_name` field and it looks more reliable if we does not hide `ExampleClass` if it occurs in another, for example, a verbose `stack_trace` or performance-related JSON field. Any guess for the question related to the `!~` operator? I've also updated the question a little bit.

Comment: Yes the `!~` works after the `json` if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, I've asked about that. Thank you for the support, finally I've figured it out (see my answer).

Comment: great! glad you have it now :)